# nginx configuration. how to give different web sites different names?

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver

i have a pointer from sites-enables/qooxdoo to /var/www/qooxdoo/nginx.conf where i have the following:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied


    root /var/www/qooxdoo;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;
}
```

to access that web site i need to do: localhost/
that's it. but how do I give a name to that web site?

Sort of localhost/site1 for example.

Thanks in advance for your help
jenia ivlev

Comment: what kind of name do you want to give ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you exactly want to achieve. Considering the following directories in your filesystem.

```
/var/www
  - site-1
  - site-2
  - ...
  - site-n
```

Now you can work with simple directories in the URL if you configure nginx like you've done.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

Requesting `http://localhost/site-1` will return the content of the file `/var/www/site-1/index.html` (and the same for `site-2` up to `site-n`).

If you want to use sub domains you can do the following.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site-1;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name site-1.localhost;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site-2;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name site-2.localhost;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site-n;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name site-n.localhost;
}
```

Requesting `http://site-1.localhost/` will return the content of the file `/var/www/site-1/index.html` (and the same for `site-2` up to `site-n`).